# Ruby 1.8.x, Locking a select statement and concurrency issue

Tags: ruby, concurrency

I have a web interface and a mobile app running the same application where users can create contents (saving a collection of images with a title). These contents are user-specific and are stored into a web server running a Rails Restful WS with MySQL.

This is the content's table:

```
galleries(id, title, serialized_images, user_id, created_at, updated_at)
```

I use a version number within each content, to keep track of new inserts/updates and synchronize the mobile APP without sending back all contents each time. This number automatically increments after every new update/insert, so that the mobile APP retrieves only contents that are greater than the latest version reached. This version_number is stored into a support table like this:

```
gallery_versions(is, gallery_id, version)
```

---

The operations are performed in this order:

1. insert the gallery object
2. run an observer that:

   1. select max version_number from support table
   2. increment the version_number into the support table

The problem is concurrent insert statements. If the same user creates new contents simultaneously from the web and the app, there's the risk of 2 objects getting the same version_number.

I was wondering to lock the select max, and release this lock after the update of version_number. But with Ruby 1.8.7 I don't know how to do it.

Have you any idea?

Comment: What prevents you from using the `updated_at` column to identify updated data?

Comment: What prevents you from upgrading to a supported version of Ruby"  Ruby 1.8.y is dead, long live Ruby 1.8.7!

Comment: I cannot update the Ruby version for many reasons. And I cannot rely on the updated_at column... that won't solve my concurrency problems. With ruby 1.9 there is a great method called "with_block": is there a similar function on Ruby 1.8.x?

Comment: I think it would solve your issue as you don't need a seperate table anymore.

Comment: Can you explain your idea? There'll be 2 different records. The problem stands for SELECT statements of the MAX(version_number) before the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Select for update which will instantiate a row level lock may be the answer.  ruby 1.8.7 example:

```
Account.transaction do
  # select * from accounts where name = 'shugo' limit 1 for update
  shugo = Account.find(:first, :conditions => "name = 'shugo'", :lock => true)
  yuko = Account.find(:first, :conditions => "name = 'yuko'", :lock => true)
  shugo.balance -= 100
  shugo.save!
  yuko.balance += 100
  yuko.save!
end
```

More information at this site:
http://www.rubydox.net/class/activerecord/2.3.2/ActiveRecord%3A%3ALocking%3A%3APessimistic